# How can I install Ruby gems on a Mac behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: ruby, macos, proxy, rubygems, installation

I am trying to install ruby gems on my MacOS OS X 10.5.1 behind a corporate firewall proxy. But I am getting an error about `connection refused`.

How can I install Ruby gems on a Mac behind a corporate proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Specify the proxy to use:

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://username:password@proxyserver.net:port/'
```

If it's a Windows proxy (common in EnterpriseLand), it will use a custom NTLM authentication, which normal Unix apps don't do. To fix it, get NTLMAPS - a small Python app that acts as a local regular proxy and handballs your credential via NTLM authentication to the Windows proxy.

Comment: Is not working for me on OS X 10.10.2, gem 2.2.2. The env var is set, also wget can download the file (so the var is correct). Using '--http-proxy' works ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111181/ruby-gem-installation-problem-on-mac-which-is-behind-firewall)).

Answer (score 0):

Download the gem to your harddrive and install it manually by doing

```
gem install gem_file.gem
```