# Ruby gem installation problem on Mac which is behind firewall

Tags: ruby, proxy, rubygems

Please provide me solution for the problem of,
1) How to install ruby gems on a Mac (OS X 10.5.1) which is behind a corporate firewall.

Regards,
Sun

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby gem install error on MAC pc due to behind corporate proxy ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111008/ruby-gem-install-error-on-mac-pc-due-to-behind-corporate-proxy)

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that you use an HTTP proxy, there is a `--http-proxy` option for the `gem` app.

```
gem install --http-proxy http://corporate-proxy:1234 <gem_name>
```

Answer (score 3):

On my Mac which has the default ruby installed on it. I use the script below and it worked:

```
sudo gem install <gem_name> -p http://corporate-proxy:1234
```